# Powershell and Jenkins - Execute Powershell Script as another user

Tags: powershell, authentication, jenkins, automation

I have an environment formed by a Jenkins Server, a couple of Jenkins Slaves (windows) and several remote windows computers all part of the same domain.

I need to run a jenkins job, which executes a powershell snippet consisted of several functions (part of a custom modules loaded on the Jenkins Slave) against other windows remote computers in the same domain (which do not have the modules installed).

These modules needs to run under a specific domain account with permissions to access the remote computers.

If I logon with on any of the jenkins slave (with that specific domain account) everything works fine.

By default, Jenkins executes the job on the slave using the ***NT authority\system*** account which, of course, returns me denied access errors.

Question: is there a way to tell Jenkins to execute the Job on the windows slave with another specific Domain Account and not the **NT Authority\System** one?

Tried already:

- Invoke-command using credentials: this is not an option since the remote computers do not have the modules
- Impersonation: tried a couple of functions found on the PS gallery but do not work

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this issue? I am looking at something similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can run powershell as a process in a script and call that from Jenkins. In the script also you can use like:

```
$username = 'username'
$password = 'password'
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username,$securePassword

Start-Process Powershell.exe -Credential $credential
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is that I can't save the credentials in clear text a in a .ps1 file. Also, If I run powershell like that I won't be able to take advantage of that specific authenticated session from jenkins. Hope it makes sense.